# Migrating working sets from old to new Domino Designer installation

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I am trying to migrate my working sets to a new installation. While searching the web I found [this link](http://blog.thimojansenit.nl/2011/05/recover-designer-working-sets.html) which says that by copying the file **`<DATA FOLDER>\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\workingsets.xml`** we can get our original working sets back. I tried it, but it only restores my working sets and they are empty with no database inside them.

What am I missing here? Does any one know how to get all the working sets from old installation and put it into new installation of Domino Designer?

Answer (score 0):

Databases in designer are held as eclipse projects, so you would need to copy project directories inside workspace directory. You can see their directory names in designer just after database title.
Although, I wouldn't recommend that, because different designer versions may have different structure of its content.

Comment: Copying project files from `workspace` directory didn't work! But taking some cues I tried to search if there are any additional files of projects and I was able to find it in folder `\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects` and a file `com.ibm.designer.domino.ide.resources\wsInfo.xml`. So I copied them also. But no luck. Any other ideas regarding this? Also I was using 8.5.3 as my previous and new Domino Designer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I migrated from the same Notes 8.5.3 release on the old computer to the new computer, so after reading the tips above, I decided to just replace the whole workspace folder under the C:\Lotus\Notes\Data\ folder on my new PC with the workspace folder on my old PC.

It worked!  When I opened the Designer client, I had all my working sets complete with database icons.  I don't know anything about the workspace folder, so I probably would be cautious applying such an approach if I were migrating to a new release, but since I had not yet started to work on the new PC, I was prepare to reinstall the software if necessary.

FYI, if you don't want to lose your custom commands in the Domino Administrator client when migrating to a new PC or when installing another release of Notes on the same PC, you simply copy the domadmin.nsf database file from the old environment and replace the one in the new environment (if it exists, it won't yet exist if you haven't launched the app after a new install).  If you have upgraded to a new Notes release, then open this domadmin.nsf DB in Designer in the new environment and refresh its design from the StdAdminDatabase template (domadmin.ntf).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.lotusguru.com/lotusguru/LGBlog.nsf/d6plinks/20100310-83ESQC

The Notes client being totally closed, backup or restore the following directories :

..data/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/..

- com.ibm.designer.domino.ide.resources
- org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects
- org.eclipse.core.resources/.root
- org.eclipse.core.resources/.safetable
- org.eclipse.ui.workbench